# WinJS: Promise chain sometimes sticks after usage of BackgroundUploader class on 512MB WinPhone8.1 Emu

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, promise, winjs

I have strange error that sometimes occurs on my WinJS app on the Windows Phone 8.1 512MB RAM Emulator. I couldn't reproduce it on other Emulator instances or on device.

The execution runs through the promise chain and finishes the following return statement:

```
  return ( currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync() );
```

After that nothing happens.
I set breakpoints at all three functions (success, failure, pending) that are given to the .then definition. None of these three function code will ever be reached when this strange case occurs.

I also put this return statement on a try catch block but there was no exception to catch.

short explanation of code:

- Background Uploader instance is created (custom headers + PUT method)
- StorageFile is opened by URI
- Background uploader prepares upload of that file (definition of uploadOperation)
- uploadOperation will be started

see full code:

```
var currentUpload;  // global

 function uploadFile(localFullPath, headers, serverUrl)
 {
    var fileUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appdata:///local' + localFullPath),
        uploader = false;

        try
        {
            uploader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader();
            uploader.method = 'PUT';

            // set headers to uploader
            for (var key in headers)
            {
                if (headers.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    uploader.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
            }
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            // error handling
            return false;
        }

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileUri)
        .then(function success(file)
        {
            return uploader.createUpload(serverUrl, file);
        },
        function failure(error)
        {
            return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('file not found');
        })

        .then(function (uploadOperation)
        {
            if (currentUpload == 'Canceled')
                return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('upload canceled');
            else
                return ( currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync() );

        })

        .then(function success(success)
        {
            currentUpload = false;
            // success handling
            return true;
        }, function failure(error)
        {
            currentUpload = false;
            // error handling
            return false;
        }

        }, function pending(status)
        {
            var progress = status.progress,
                percent = Math.round(progress.bytesSent / progress.totalBytesToSend * 100);

            // progress handling
        });
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

P.S. I also got a deprecated warning, although I'm not using group/TransferGroup on the BackgroundUploader class:

> The method Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.IBackgroundTransferBase.put_Group
>   has been deprecated. Group may be altered or unavailable for releases
>   after Windows 8.1. Instead, use TransferGroup.

Maybe it is related to that promise chain error.

Comment: I frankly don't understand what you're trying to achieve with `return ( currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync() );`. Also you've messed up you promise chaining. When chaining promises, error handling must me done at the end and for all of them. That's the beauty of promise chaining.

Comment: This statement saves the current upload in a global variable. Imagine it would be return uploadOperation.startAsync() - tested it, error also occured then. What do you mean with "messed up"? Are you talking about best practice and style or could this lead to an error? The reason I did this what that it only gave me a "WinRT error" so the I couldn't properly differentiate between the errors (there is a text but this is bound to a specific language).

Comment: According to the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation.startasync.aspx), that function can degrade performance. Perhaps you are experiencing a slowdown. They recommend "that you call StartAsync on a background worker thread..." Could this be the source of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a simple typo error ??
Just check the comments in code*s* below

```js
var currentUpload;  // global

 function uploadFile(localFullPath, headers, serverUrl)
 {
    var fileUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appdata:///local' + localFullPath),
        uploader = false;

        try
        {
            uploader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader();
            uploader.method = 'PUT';

            // set headers to uploader
            for (var key in headers)
            {
                if (headers.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    uploader.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
            }
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            // error handling
            return false;
        }

        /*

         return something it's a good practice if you want to chain Promises
           |
           |
           V                                                                       */  
        return Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileUri)
        .then(
          function success(file){
            return uploader.createUpload(serverUrl, file);
          },
          function failure(error){
            return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('file not found');
  //                                        |_____________|  
  // your are rejecting your promise with ---------^
          }
        ).then(
          function (uploadOperation){

  // Just avoid this type of code construction
  // and add brace !
  // adding brace augment readability and prevent errors !

           // where do you set this ??? currentUpload = 'Canceled'
           // is part of winjs ???
           if (currentUpload == 'Canceled') 

           // why not handle your rejected promise ?
           // by something like :
           //if( uploadOperation == 'file not found' )
                return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('upload canceled');
            else
                return ( currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync() );
          }
        ).then(
// Promise resolve handler
          function success(success){
            currentUpload = false;
            // success handling
            return true;
          } , 
// Promise reject handler
          function failure(error){
            currentUpload = false;
            // error handling
            return false;
          }
/*        ^  
          |
YOU HAVE HERE A DOUBLE CLOSING BRACE }} ???
 °
 |  WHAT IS THIS PART FOR ??????
 |
 +------+---- Ending uploadFile with successive closing brace !
        |
        |+---------------- Declaration separator
        ||      +--- New function declaration
        ||      |
        VV      V                     */
        }, function pending(status){
            var progress = status.progress,
                percent = Math.round(progress.bytesSent / progress.totalBytesToSend * 100);
            // progress handling
        });
        }

/*
ALL THAT PART ABOVE IS NOT IN THE PROMISE CHAIN 
AND SHOULD BREAK YOUR CODE !!!
HOW HAVE YOU EVER COULD RUN THIS ???
*/
```

maybe it miss a part of your code to be sure of that, because in this state your code must break !

---

Maybe an adjustement could be :

```js
var currentUpload;  // global

function uploadFile(localFullPath, headers, serverUrl)
{
  var fileUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appdata:///local' + localFullPath),
      uploader = false;

  try
  {
    uploader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader();
    uploader.method = 'PUT';

    // set headers to uploader
    for (var key in headers)
    {
      if (headers.hasOwnProperty(key))
        uploader.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
    }
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    // error handling
    return false;
  }

  /*

  return something it's a good practice if you want to chain Promises
    |
    |
    V                                                                     */  
  return Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileUri)
  .then(
    function success(file){
      return uploader.createUpload(serverUrl, file);
    },
    function failure(error){
      return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('file not found');// O|--------+
    }//                                                             |
  ).then(//                                                         |
    function (uploadOperation){//  O|-------------------------------|
      //                                                            |
      // Just avoid this type of code construction                  |
      // and add brace !                                            |
      // adding brace augment readability and prevent errors !      |
      //                                                            |   
      // EDIT                                                       |
      //if (currentUpload == 'Canceled') { // <--- add brace        |
      if (uploadOperation == 'file not found') { //<---add brace <--+ 

        return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('upload canceled');

      } else { // <---- add braces

        // even if it is valid
        // avoid assignement like that
        // so subtil to read / understand / debug ...
        // return ( currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync() );

        currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync();
        // maybe debug here ?
        console.log('currentUpload : ' + currentUpload );
        return currentUpload;

      } // <---- add brace
    }
  ).then(
    function success(success){
      currentUpload = false;
      // success handling
      return true;
    } , 
    function failure(error){
      currentUpload = false;
      // error handling
      return false;
    } ,
    function pending(status){
      var progress = status.progress,
          percent = Math.round(progress.bytesSent / progress.totalBytesToSend * 100);
      // progress handling
    }
  ).done( // it is always a good thing to have a final catcher !!
    function(){
      // things are ok !
      console.log('ok');
    },
    function(err){
      // make something with your error better than
      alert(err);
      console.log('ko');

    }
  );
}
```

***EDIT***

Looking further *(i do not use winjs)*, there is something to be clarified :

```js
.then(
  function success(file) {
    return uploader.createUpload(serverUrl, file);
  },
  function failure(error) {
    return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('file not found');

  }
).then(
  function(uploadOperation) {

    if (currentUpload == 'Canceled')
      return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('upload canceled');
    else
      return (currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync());
  }
).
```

where are you setting this :
`currentUpload = 'Canceled'`
You are checking that but i'am pretty sure this part of code is never reached.
Before that your reject your promise with :
`return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('file not found');`
maybe the next `then` should handle someting like that :

```js
.then(
  function success(file) {
    return uploader.createUpload(serverUrl, file);
  },
  function failure(error) {
    return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('file not found');

  }
).then(
  function(uploadOperation) {

    if (uploadOperation == 'file not found')
      return WinJS.Promise.wrapError('upload canceled');
    else
      return (currentUpload = uploadOperation.startAsync());
  }
)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the pending(status) function is a progress function. 
`promise.then(onComplete, onError, onProgress).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );`
[ms docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/br229728.aspx) I think the .catch() is not available on WinJS - at least I couldn't find any documentation. I think a failure function on the .done part should do this job. I already tried to define them, but error still occurs.

Comment: I have updated my answer,i think you have a double closing brace in the wrong place which lead to this bad behaviour

Comment: I have, once again, modified my answer, just check the comments, particulary the part about `function(uploadOperation)`

Comment: Are you sure returning a WinJS.Promise.wrapError won't cause calling the failure function instead of the success fn? Got to try it later... I gave you the bounty for helping me